# Android 4.0 и javascript

Tags: javascript, android

Доброго времени суток. Javascript не хочет работать на версии 4.0 android(на других версиях работает). Кто знает какие могут причины и как их решить подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Возможно вы используете функции js, которые не поддерживаются Android 4.0

Comment: Другие сайты с js проверял? Если нет, то проверь, может js вообще отключен, проверь нотсы http://caniuse.com/#search=ecmascript%205

Comment: Какая версия? ES6?

Comment: Есть детали к сайту подключен <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>